# React - useEffect not using updated value in websocket onmessage

Tags: react-hooks

I have a simple issue where a state value updates in my code but is not using the new value.  Any ideas what I can do to adjust this?

```js
    const [max, setMax] = useState<number>(10);

        useEffect(() => {
             console.log('max', max);              //This outputs correct updated value.

             ws.onmessage = (message: string => {
                  console.log('max', max);         //This is always 10.

                  if (max > 100) {
                        doSomething(message);
                  }
             }
        },[]);

        function onChange() {
              setMax(1000);
        }


    <Select onChange={onChange}></Select>   //this is abbrev for simplicity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is running only once, on the initial render, using the values from initial render, so `max` variable is closure captured and not updated in any way. But the solution will be pretty simple, using `useRef` and one more `useEffect` to update the ref variable when `max` variable updates.

```js
const maxRef = useRef(10); // same value
const [max, setMax] = useState(10);

// Only used to update ref variable
useEffect(() => {
  maxRef.current = max;
}, [max]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("max", maxRef.current);

  ws.onmessage = (message) => {
    console.log("max", maxRef.current);

    if (maxRef.current > 100) {
      doSomething(message);
    }
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: sheesh easy.  Thanks @Sergey